# Retrieving a form results with requests

Tags: python, python-requests, mechanize, forms, robobrowser

I want to submit a multipart/form-data that sets the input for a simulation on [TRILEGAL](http://stev.oapd.inaf.it/cgi-bin/trilegal), and download the file available from a redirected page.

I studied documentation of requests, urllib,  Grab, mechanize, etc. , and it seems that in mechanize my code would be :

```
from mechanize import Browser
browser = Browser()
browser.open("http://stev.oapd.inaf.it/cgi-bin/trilegal")
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser['gal_coord'] = ["2"]
browser['eq_alpha'] = ["277.981111"]
browser['eq_delta'] = ["-19.0833"]
response = browser.submit()
content = response.read()
```

However, I could not test it because it is not available in python 3.

So I tried requests :

```
import requests
url = 'http://stev.oapd.inaf.it/cgi-bin/trilegal'
values = {'gal_coord':"2",
        'eq_alpha':"277.981111",
        'eq_delta':"-19.0833",
        'field':" 0.047117",
          }
r = requests.post(url, files = values)
```

but I can't figure out how to get to the results page - if I do

```
r.content
```

it displays the content of the form that I had just submitted, whereas if you open the actual [website](http://stev.oapd.inaf.it/cgi-bin/trilegal), and click 'submit', you see a new window  (following the method="post"  action="./trilegal_1.6" ).

How can I get to that new window with requests (i.e. follow to the page that opens up when I click the submit button) ,  and click the link on the results page to retrieve the results file (  "The results will be available after about 2 minutes at THIS LINK.")  ?

If you can point me to any other tool that could do the job I would be really grateful - I spent hours looking through SO for something that could help solve this problem.

Thank you!

Chris

Comment: You need to open that link to get the data from file

Comment: Hi! but what link ? If I open http://stev.oapd.inaf.it/cgi-bin/trilegal_1.6  it opens the input, not the results page....

Comment: Right, in that page you have to open THIS LINK after 2 minutes

Comment: there is a new link generated each time you submit the form.  How can I find out what is the link ?

Comment: The link is present in `page source`

Comment: but how can I get to that new page?  1) access with requests http://stev.oapd.inaf.it/cgi-bin/trilegal  2) submit the form  3) access the results page.  I don't know how to do the last step.

Comment: Your target is to download that file, right ?

Comment: yes, to download the file. New file is generated each time you submit the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150769/discussion-between-ksai-and-scichris).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working solution for `python 2.7`

```
from mechanize import Browser
from urllib import urlretrieve # for download purpose
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = Browser()
browser.open("http://stev.oapd.inaf.it/cgi-bin/trilegal")
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser['gal_coord'] = ["2"]
browser['eq_alpha'] = ["277.981111"]
browser['eq_delta'] = ["-19.0833"]
response = browser.submit()
content = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
base_url = 'http://stev.oapd.inaf.it'

# fetch the url from page source and it to base url
link = soup.findAll('a')[0]['href'].split('..')[1]
url = base_url + str(link)
filename = 'test.dat'

# now download the file
urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Your file will be downloaded as `test.dat`. You can open it with respective program.

Comment: So actually when running that I get an error about browser['eq_delta'] = ["-19.0833"]  :  TypeError: must assign a string.  Thanks to your suggestion to resolve to using mechanize, I have another working answer below

Answer (score 1):

I post a separate answer because it would be too cluttered. Thanks to @ksai,  this works in python 2.7 :

```
import re
import time
from mechanize import Browser

browser = Browser()
browser.open("http://stev.oapd.inaf.it/cgi-bin/trilegal")
browser.select_form(nr=0) 

#set appropriate form contents 
browser['gal_coord'] = ["2"]
browser['eq_alpha'] = "277.981111"
browser['eq_delta'] = "-19.0833"
browser['field'] = " 0.047117" 
browser['photsys_file'] = ["tab_mag_odfnew/tab_mag_lsst.dat"]
browser["icm_lim"] = "3"
browser["mag_lim"] = "24.5"                                
response = browser.submit()

# wait 1 min while results are prepared
time.sleep(60)

# select the appropriate url
url = 'http://stev.oapd.inaf.it/' + str(browser.links()[0].url[3:])

# download the results file 
browser.retrieve(url, 'test1.dat')
```

Thank you very much!
Chris